# How to get id of someone got mentioned

Tags: javascript, discord.js

So what I mean with someone got mentioned like for example `!kill @user`, I tried to use `message.mentions.users.first().id` but it kept giving me `undefined` ,I want it to get the `id` of the user that got mentioned and log it. I couldn't find any tutorials or anything that solved my issue like when i type !kill @user, I want the `console` to log the id

Comment: I tested it and it works. Could you add more of your code on here?

Comment: oh nvm i just found the issue i added make it  async the message in the command

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**To sum up:** `message.mentions.users.first().id` is the correct syntax.

make sure your `bot.on("message")` event listener is working as intended if it returns undefined.